# grep and brackets in text

Tags: bash, grep

I store downloaded files in a log like this:

```
[source] filename
```

To avoid downloading a file more than once I grep for `[source] filename` before:

```
if ! grep "$signature" downloaded.log > /dev/null; then
    wget ...
fi
```

**but** starting my line with `[` grep does not work the way I need:

```
signature="[source] filename"
echo $signature | grep "$signature"
echo $signature | grep "\$signature" #trying to escape first bracket
```

both return nothing.

Any smart workaround?

It would be nice also having no need to change the code switching to parens `()`, braces `{}`, or whatever `<>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you have to quote your variable, then you should use `-F` `--fixed-strings` switch to avoid interpreting the brackets as regular expression meta characters:

```
echo "$signature" | grep -F "$signature"
```

Then you should also use `-q` `--quiet` switch too, so `grep` exit as soon as found the first occurrence. This only for speed consideration:

```
if ! grep -Fq "$signature" downloaded.log; then
    wget ...
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to test it. You are right about quoting variables, just forgot them writing question

Comment: @neurino One more thing: you should add the `-x` (match whole line) option to `grep`, otherwise a line like `[foo] I say [source] filename, so there!` will match. Note that this means `[source] filename2` won't match (definitely desirable), nor will `[source] filename was read` (may or may not be desirable).

Comment: @Gilles: `-x` option is definitely desirable, thank you very much